# Calculating the mean and variance in R without the built in functions (HW question)

Tags: r

[image]

so I am not sure if I am doing this right:
X<-c(64,38,97,88,24,14,104,83)

so I would approach this by sum(x)/length

For the variance, I am just lost

However my professor would like us to use the formula of the sum so I am lost, I am a beginner in R so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you calculate the mean, store that value into its own variable, ex `M <- sum(X) / length(X)`. This way you can reference it when you perform the variance calculation

Comment: Not to mention, the formula for variance is incorrect as shown in the question; the summation should only include the numerator, like so: $$\frac{ \sum \left( X_i - \bar{X} \right) ^2 }{n-1}$$

Comment: This looks like an R programming question rather than mathematics.

Comment: I got it thank you !!

Comment: For the third part of the question would it be ?                                                      Xnew<-X[X>50]
[1]  64  97  88 104  83

Comment: @WaveX, the formula for the variance is not wrong: since the denominator is a factor $1/(n-1)$ it's irrelevant if it's in or outside of the summation

Comment: Regarding the code, all you need is: 1) mean: `sum(X)/length(X)` or `mean(X)`; 2) variance: `sum((X-mean(X))^2)/(length(X)-1)`

Comment: @PaulG indeed, guess that's what taking too quick a glance at the summation gets me. Good catch! (My mind interpreted the $n-1$ on the bottom as $i-1$)

Answer (score 0):

Prohibited loops must be ones you program *explicitly,* otherwise
this is an impossible task. (Of course, we don't know what you
learned in 'Lecture 1').

In the code below, R uses an *internal* loop to get the sum.

```
x = c(5,3,7,9);  sum(x)
[1] 24
```

Now for your problem:

(1) Explicitly prohibited:

```
x = c(64,38,97,88,24,14,104,83)
a = mean(x);  v = var(x)
a;  v  
[1] 64
[1] 1200.286
```

(2) Legal to use `sum` and `length`?

```
a = sum(x)/length(x)
v = sum((x-a)^2)/(length(x)-1)
a; v
[1] 64
[1] 1200.286
v1 = (sum(x^2) - 8*a^2)/7
v1
[1] 1200.286
```

(3) The following should be OK, provided it's allowed to count how many observations there are. [However, even adding just `64 + 38 + 97` must require an internal loop at some level.]

```
a = (64 + 38 + 97 + 88 + 24 + 14 + 104 + 83)/8;  a
[1] 64
ssq = (64^2 + 38^2 + 97^2 + 88^2 + 24^2 + 14^2 + 104^2 + 83^2) 
(ssq - 8*a^2)/7
[1] 1200.286
```

*Note:* The method used for `v1` in the second section and to get
the variance in the last section, is OK for small numbers of
observations of moderate size (as in this example) and with no intermediate rounding.
Otherwise, in spite of being *algebraically* correct, it can
result in *computational* errors.

The formula used for the numerator of the sample variance is
as follows, where the last two versions can present computational
difficulties:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - n\bar X^2\\ = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac 1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2.$$

```
set.seed(222)
x = rnorm(100, 1000, .01)
var(x)
[1] 9.17813e-05
sum((x-mean(x))^2)/99
[1] 9.17813e-05
```

However:

```
(sum(x^2) - 100*mean(x)^2)/99
[1] 9.178137e-05
(sum(x^2) - (sum(x)^2)/100)/99
[1] 9.178152e-05
```

Comment: It's quite unlikely that the problem in the OP meant anything more than a for-loop ;).